# Why does this script not work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am using jquery 1.10.2 and the following call to my dialogOpen function works fine in IE9+ but I am getting the following error in IE8:

Object does not support this property or method.  Any ideas ?

```
dialogOpen($(this).attr("id"), $(this).find(".tdStyle").html().trim(),     $(this).find(".tdQtyOnHand").html().trim(), $(this),  $(this).find(".tdPlantID").html().trim());
```

Thanks

Comment: `$(this).find(".tdStyle").html().trim()` `.trim()` is the problem. The error message should have made that obvious. Doing a little research on that method would indicate that it isn't supported in IE<9

Comment: @KevinB IE8's error messages aren't terribly helpful. It simply states that `Object does not support this property or method`. It could have been any dereference point (a `.`) in that line, not necessarily `.trim()`, as far as what we can glean directly from the error message. Obviously someone familiar with this kind of error, and jQuery chaining, can spot pretty quickly that it's likely `.trim()`, but that requires experience.

Comment: Kevin B and ajp15243 thank you for the responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.html()` returns a String object and IE doesn't support the `.trim()` method on String, fortunately jQuery provides an alternative, [`$.trim(String)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/).  You can also add it yourself (but honestly with jQuery already loaded why would you) by following [this exhaustive article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) (which would allow you to keep your original code entirely unmodified):

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '');
  };
}
```

Comment: That and it's IE8 ... the sooner the world stops supporting it the better :-P

Comment: True, maybe I should hush up about how to overcome IE 8 and just offer a link to http://browsehappy.com/ :) This missing method in IE bit me a few times

Comment: why ms do not prompt users to upgrade like everyone else I do not understand

Comment: @andrew They do on their "paid" products. My Windows won't stfu about telling me to upgrade right now but I already know the update 'causes an error on my network, so I'm like NO! and it just comes back eventually like "hey, hey, you need to update!" They could careless if you upgrade their free stuff.

Comment: @andrew, they FINALLY started to after [IE 10](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9238819/Microsoft_s_browser_auto_update_pays_off_as_IE10_share_doubles) but yes it took way too long.  I think I read a Joel on Software blog about how they were paranoid of breaking enterprise web apps, so they did everything to keep the platform as stable as possible (bugs and all)

Comment: @andrew some companies have a bunch of PCs with Windows XP, so we have to try to make things work in IE8.

Comment: ^ Exactly. You can't blame Microsoft for other companies' bad development dependency choices.

Comment: Yes you can, expecially when one of the main problem is those danded dactums at Military bases. Someone tell the president to upgrade the basis already! We got nsa hijacking people's call while a General has to call me for tech support at Rucker because his IE8 won't load their outdated Sharepoint Program! (True Story!) Fact is, if MS didn't mess up so many patches, companies like the US military wouldn't be so scared to upgrade. Their FF approvals for upgrades go through almost immediately after release, but not IE! Y? Because MS won't stop messin up updates!